# Float return 0 when the value is under 1

Tags: php

I have a problem. I print a value with echo function doesn't print result, but with var_dump return value.

```
//$issue['fields']['timeestimate'] value is 2700
echo $this->toHours($issue['fields']['timeestimate']); return nothing
var_dump($this->toHours($issue['fields']['timeestimate'])); return float(0.75)
```

The function is

```
private function toHours($seconds){
        return $seconds/3600;
}
```

What's wrong? If the value is 1, or higher, it returns the correct value.

Comment: Try http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php I think that's what you're after...

Comment: Most likely it's a precision issue. Read the big red box http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Comment: not works. the echo function continues returning nothing.

Comment: This code here is fine, the bug must be somewhere else. Encoding? Spaces or special chars in the `timeestimate`. please show all  `var_dump($issue['fields']['timeestimate'])`  `var_dump($seconds/3600)` `var_dump($this->toHours($issue['fields']['timeestimate']));` for real (copy&paste)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the loop that handled it, sorry ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can convert to a numeric value before the division:

```
private function toHours($seconds){
        $seconds = intval($seconds);
        return $seconds/3600;
}
```

And use **printf()** to show the formatted float value, like:

```
printf('%f', $this->toHours($issue['fields']['timeestimate']));
```